# How to use file_get_contents($filename) with $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] to get filename?

Tags: php

I am using `file_put_contents($filename, $jpg)` to upload my jpg files to some location. 
How to use `file_get_contents ($filename);` with `($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"])`?
I am trying something like `$jpg = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];
    $img = $_GET["img"];
    $filename = "applicantsPhotos/applicantPhoto". mktime(). ".jpg";
    file_put_contents($filename, $jpg);
    echo file_get_contents ($filename); die;`

but this is not working well(neigther I am getting filename, Not die stops script). Am I using wrong method to get the name ?

Comment: Define more precisely what `not working well` means? What is the error (if any)?

Comment: thanks for comment. But "not working well" means I am not getting file name as a string there. Nor die is working (Script is not getting stop)

Answer (score 1):

You should know what is exactly **raw** `POST` data:
`$_POST` can be said as and outcome after **splitting** the `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`, PHP splits the raw post data and formats in the way we see it in the `$_POST`

For example if `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` looks something like this:

`key1=value1&key2=value2`

then `$_POST` would look like this:

```
$_POST = array(
     "key1" => "value1",
     "key2" => "value2",);
```

Most probably you include some other things (elements) from the post in your `*.jpg` data. Make sure you include only raw and valid `*.jpg` picture information, not other elements.

Also keep in mind that  `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is not available with form's type `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

To get the Raw Post Data use:

`<?php $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); ?>`

`php://input` is a **read-only stream** that allows you to read raw data from the request body. In the case of `POST` requests, **it is preferable** to use `php://input` instead of `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` as it *does not depend* on special `php.ini` directives.

More information [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php), [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data) and [here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

Comment: Thanks for help. But is there any way that I can get the file name.So that I can pass it to any other file.

Comment: actually I am calling above mention PHP file from flash. And I want to store/Pass name of uploaded file to some other file